# What is the command to get the .listing file from SFTP server using cURL command

Tags: linux, curl, ftp, wget, sftp

In wget I am trying to get the list of files and its properties from FTP server using below Wget command,

```
wget --no-remove-listing ftp://myftpserver/ftpdirectory/
```

This will generate two files: .listing (this is what I am looking in cURL) and index.html which is the html version of the listing file.

**My expectation:**
In cURL how to achieve this scenario?
What is the command to get the .listing and index.html file from FTP/SFTP server **using CURL**.

Comment: `curl --list-only ftp://myftpserver/ftpdirectory` ?

Comment: I am getting list in the commnad prompt, no file are creating in the directory like wget command, I tried below commands

-sh-3.00$ curl -n --list-only ftp://64.125.117.2:21/dgt_outgoing/
inv.dat
nv.dat.tag
azz.dat

Comment: i tried 2 more options, but unable to get the .listing file.

-sh-3.00$ curl -n dont-remove-listing ftp://myftpserver/ftpdirectory
-sh-3.00$ curl -n no-remove-listing ftp://myftpserver/ftpdirectory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I found on http://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#How_do_I_get_an_FTP_directory_li

If you end the FTP URL you request with a slash, libcurl will provide you with a directory listing of that given directory. You can also set CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST to alter what exact listing command libcurl would use to list the files.

The follow-up question that tend to follow the previous one, is how a program is supposed to parse the directory listing. How does it know what's a file and what's a dir and what's a symlink etc. The harsh reality is that FTP provides no such fine and easy-to-parse output. The output format FTP servers respond to LIST commands are entirely at the server's own liking and the NLST output doesn't reveal any types and in many cases don't even include all the directory entries. Also, both LIST and NLST tend to hide unix-style hidden files (those that start with a dot) by default so you need to do "LIST -a" or similar to see them.

Thanks & Regards,
Alok

Comment: Thank Alok. I used -a option but i am getting list in the command box, Is there anyway to write these directory list in some files. Before downloading the files from SFTP server to linux box i want to check the file whether when is it received and size of the file then i want to start download the files..

Comment: Is there any equal command or package to download the files against cURL from SFTP server to linux box. Please help me out

Comment: Have you tried to redirect to a file ? `curl ftp://myftpserver/ftpdirectory/ > .listing`

Comment: great Mali, now it's working.. Is this works for if i use SFTP instead of ftp server.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked it on WIN->CygWin and it works for me:

Do not forget to use `/` at the end of the path.

```
$ curl -s -l -u test1@test.com:Test_PASSWD --ftp-ssl 'ftps://ftp.test.com/Ent/'
```